# Tikzscale fails for group plot with three elements, but works for two elements

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, tikzscale

For a custom figure I wanted to stack three figures on top of each other, to keep readability (multiple y axis) and comparability (all figures have the same x axis, the third figure is a combination of figure one and two). To be able to scale the figure properly I intended to use `tikzscale`. To test my code I wrote a small test sample, with main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-cache/]
%\tikzset{external/force remake}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth, height=1.2\linewidth]{stacked_test_simple.tikz}
        %\resizebox{.8\linewidth}{1.2\linewidth}{\input{stacked_test_simple.tikz}}
        \caption{Image II}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and stacked_test_simple.tikz:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
    \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.498039215686275,0.0549019607843137}
    
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            % set how the plots should be organized
            group size=1 by 3,
            % only show ticklabels and axis labels on the bottom
            x descriptions at=edge bottom,
            % set the `vertical sep' to zero
            vertical sep=0pt,
        },
        ]
        % start the first plot
        \nextgroupplot[
        tick align=outside,
        tick pos=left,
        x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
        xmajorgrids,
        xmin=1, xmax=5,
        xtick style={color=black},
        y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
        y label style={color=color0},
        yticklabel style={color=color0},
        xmajorticks=false,
        ylabel={Plot 1},
        ymajorgrids,
        ymin=0, ymax = 26,
        ytick style={color=black}
        ]
        \addplot [line width=1pt, color0]
        table {%
            1 1
            2 4
            3 9
            4 16
            5 25
        };
        \nextgroupplot[
        tick align=outside,
        tick pos=left,
        x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
        ytick style={color=color0},
        xmajorgrids,
        xmajorticks=false,
        xmin=1, xmax=5,
        xtick style={color=black},
        y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
        y label style = {color=color0},
        yticklabel style={color=color0},
        ylabel={Plot 2},
        ymajorgrids,
        ymin = -6, ymax = 0,
        ytick style={color=black}
        ]
        \addplot [semithick, color0, mark=square*, mark size=2, mark options={solid}, only marks]
        table {%
            1 -1
            2 -2
            3 -3
            4 -4
            5 -5
        };
        \nextgroupplot[tick align=outside,
        tick pos=left,
        x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
        xlabel={X data},
        xmajorgrids,
        xmin=1, xmax=5,
        xtick style={color=black},
        y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
        ylabel style={color=color0},
        ylabel={Plot 3},
        ymajorgrids,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 6,
        ytick style={color=black},
        yticklabel style={color=color0}
        ]
        \addplot [semithick, color0, mark=square*, mark size=2, mark options={solid}, only marks]
        table {%
            1 1
            2 2
            3 3
            4 4
            5 5
        };
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but compilation fails for each `\nextgroupplot` with

```
Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot height `-316.93126pt' is too small. This 
cannot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label 
sizes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your height..
```

It works fine if I use `\input` and `resizebox`, i.e. without `tikzscale`, but that will damage my fonts. It also works fine if I reduce the amount of stacked plots to two and use `tikzscale`.
Why is tikzscale failing for my case, and what can I do to fix that issue (or what kind of different approach could I use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is not indended to address all points in my question, but at least to point out a solution to my issues. Resizing the stacked plot worked by including the targeted size directly in the groupplot-definition:

```
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        % set how the plots should be organized
        group size=1 by 3,
        % only show ticklabels and axis labels on the bottom
        x descriptions at=edge bottom,
        % set the `vertical sep' to zero
        vertical sep=0pt,
    },
    heigth=0.4\linewidth,
    width=0.8\linewidth,
    ]
```

and including the figure with

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{stacked_test_simple.tikz}
```

This allows at least scaling, even though it requires a more indirect approach.